# videoview oncompletionlistener not called in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

i am displaying images and video in imageview and videoview but the issue is when video is 
playing onpreparedlistener called but when video finish oncompletion listener not called
when videoview complete i increment the i for next video or images

also it gives me error in logcat like this but video is playing

> 10-29 20:12:47.770: E/MediaPlayer(3975): error (1, -2147483648)

```
private void nextVideo(String path){

        mImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    if(mVideoview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
        mVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    controller = new MediaController(HomeActivityNewViewPager.this);
    mVideoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    mVideoview.setMediaController(null);
    controller.setMediaPlayer(mVideoview);

    mVideoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    mVideoview.start();
                    long duration = mVideoview.getDuration();
                    second=duration;
                    //handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    //handler.postDelayed(runnable,second);

       }
   });


    mVideoview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

               Log.v("video view completed","---"+i);

               mp.reset();

               if(automode){

                   if(i==myplaylistlocal.size() || i>myplaylistlocal.size())
                   {

                       String checkcount=spreferences.getString("roundcount", "");
                       Log.v("roundcount==Before Integer.parseInt","---->"+roundcount);
                       if(roundcount>=Integer.parseInt(checkcount))
                       {   
                           roundcount=0;
                           Log.v("roundcount==After Integer.parseInt","---->"+roundcount);
                           updateplaylist();
                       }

                       i=0;                                                
                       indexplus();
                       imagesautomode();
                       i++;

                   }
                   else if(i==myplaylistlocal.size()-1)
                   {
                       imagesautomode();
                       i++;
                   }
                   else{
                       imagesautomode();
                   }

               }
               else{
                   i++;
                   images();
               }



        }
    });

    mVideoview.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

            Log.v("Error in video playing","----->"+i);

            return true;
        }

    }); 

}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors back from the video player? Some codes might be improper format etc. I have noticed some videos are encoded incorrectly and end before the video player perceives they finished.

Comment: 10-29 20:12:47.770: E/MediaPlayer(3975): error (1, -2147483648) this is display in logcat but still onerrorlistner not called

Answer (score 0):

Either way, the error referenced above is MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN. If this video was made for this app, I would make sure that it is properly encoded for Android. Also make sure that is clearly defines its endpoint.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN

this is a work around but could possbly work in your situation:

```
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN) 
        //ERROR UNKNOWN - COULD BE IMPROPERLY FORMATTED VIDEO {
        //MOVE ON TO NEXT VIDEO
        //DO LOGGING
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I have ran into a situation where custom videos have improper end tags and the media player does not know how to finish them. Is the video you are trying use a custom video?